# Setting breakpoint in VSCode results in "Breakpoint ignored because target path not found"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Attempting to add a breakpoint results in the message. In VSCode settings I enabled "Allow Breakpoints Everywhere" but still have the issue.
The code and environment is setup using the Yeoman Teams Generator.

Comment: Please add your `launch.json` `tsocnfig` and any other config files you are using for your project to get some clarity

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a misconfigured Azure Bot Messaging endpoint.